# Updating columns in row in sequence after one cell is changed

Tags: vba, excel

My worksheet is basically a metrics worksheet that has multiple columns that rely on a date entered into one column, but each of these later columns then rely on each other in sequence for setting dates and time periods.

I'm trying to find a way to update certain columns within the same row when that first value is changed; through the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event if possible (or some other way if the result is the same).

What I want to happen: I enter a "start" date in **column A**.  I need excel to then update **column B** of the same row based on the value in **column A**. Then I need **column C** (same row) to update based on the new value in **column B**; then I need **column D** to update based on the value in **column C**; and so on.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does make sense :) But instead of using `worksheet_selectionchange` use the `worksheet_change` event :) Give it a try and if you are still stuck then post the code that you tried :)

Comment: Good call.  I'm greedy for reputation, for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to really want VBA, so I'll post another answer (quite different from my other one).

Here I use the `Worksheet_Change` event. It calls a function that returns an array of type Variant containing dates. This array can then be written to the sheet simply using `=`.

I find this slightly more complicated than just using formulas in cells, but it has the advantage of a cleaner front-end, which you seem to want.

In the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3) = RelevantDates(Target.Value)
    End If

End Sub
```

In a code module:

```
Function RelevantDates(startDate As Date) As Variant
    Dim v As Variant
    ' Adapt to your needs:
    ReDim v(1 To 3)
    v(1) = startDate + 1 ' add one day
    v(2) = DateSerial(Year(v(1)), Month(v(1)), Day(v(1)) + 7) ' add one more week
    v(3) = DateSerial(Year(v(2)), Month(v(2)) + 1, Day(v(2))) ' add one month
    RelevantDates = v
End Function
```

Of course the above only returns 3 rather trivial dates, but you can customise this as you see fit.

[image]

Comment: Oops, I just realised the column headers are wrong in the picture. Should read: Enter your date here, A day later, A week after that, A month later. Too lazy to fix the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why any VBA would be required for this. Just write formulas in your cells. It's quite straightforward, really.

Here's an example where a date entered in column A changes the value in column B, which in turn changes the value in column C, and so on.

[image]

Row 2 shows the result of the formulas, while row 4 shows the formulas themselves (apologies for the poor formatting of these rather long formulas).

Comment: Well, that's what I was trying, but for some reason it was not working. I started with a date in Column C, which updated a date in Column E. This worked fine and always updated Column E, but the Column afterwards that depended on Column E or other columns generated off of Column E woul dnot update in sequence when the date in Column C changed.  On top of that, when the latter columns were blank they displayed errors - easy enough fix to hide from view with conditional formatting, but I'd just as soon keep the worksheet "clean" and have the recalcs done behind everything in VBA

Comment: Not working?! Is Calculation set to Automatic in your Excel options?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your later columns would just have formulas in them based on the previous columns.  Something like `=A2*100` for column B2, and `=B2+88` for column C2.

If that's not easy because the calculations are difficult, consider worksheet functions, like `=ComplicatedFunction(A2)` for column B2.

```
Function ComplicatedFunction(depended_on As Range)

    If depended_on.Value <> 0 Then
        PAYEES = 1
    Else
        PAYEES = 2
    End If
End Function
```

If that's not possible, then you're right - a worksheet changed event could help, perhaps something like:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Debug.Print "change to column A encountered"
        Range(2,Target.Row).Value = Target.Value + 2
    ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then
        Debug.Print "change to column B encountered"
        Range(3,Target.Row).Value = Target.Value + 99
    ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then
        Debug.Print "change to column C encountered"
        Range(4,Target.Row).Value = Target.Value * 7
    End If

End Sub
```

I believe the Worksheet_Change calls will be cascaded after you update values within the sub itself.

Comment: There is nothing like `WorksheetChanged` ;)

Comment: I know, it's ugly as sin.  I usually try to keep from hard-coding all those rows and columns, instead using constants (`amount_column`) to keep it a _little_ cleaner, or at least more readable...

Comment: No I didn't mean that :) What I meant was there is no event which is called `WorksheetChanged` :)

Comment: Doh!  Of course you're right.  I was copying some code from a module, in which I had cleverly used camelcase instead of matching the form method that called it. :(